# python: iterate through list and replace elements with corresponding dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

I am trying to replace list element value with value looked up in dictionary how do I do that?

```
list = [1, 3, 2, 10]  

d = {'id': 1, 'val': 30},{'id': 2, 'val': 53}, {'id': 3, 'val': 1}, {'id': 4, 'val': 9}, {'id': 5, 'val': 2}, {'id': 6, 'val': 6}, {'id': 7, 'val': 11}, {'id': 8, 'val': 89}, {'id': 9, 'val': 2}, {'id': 10, 'val': 4}

for i in list: 
    for key, v in d.iteritems():
        ???
        ???
```

so at the end I am expecting:

```
list = [30, 1, 53, 4]
```

thank you

Comment: @systempuntout: A tuple of dicts.

Comment: It is very strange Dict. If it will be {1 : 30, 2 : 53 ...} things will be easier.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
D2 = dict((x['id'], x['val']) for x in D)
L2 = [D2[x] for x in L]
```

Comment: What if the problem is the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

```
   td = (
        {'val': 30, 'id': 1},
        {'val': 53, 'id': 2},
        {'val': 1, 'id': 3},
        {'val': 9, 'id': 4},
        {'val': 2, 'id': 5},
        {'val': 6, 'id': 6},
        {'val': 11, 'id': 7},
        {'val': 89, 'id': 8},
        {'val': 2, 'id': 9},
        {'val': 4, 'id': 10}
        )

    source_list = [1, 3, 2, 10]
    final_list = []

    for item in source_list:
        for d in td:
            if d['id'] == item:
                final_list.append(d['val'])

    print('Source : ', source_list)
    print('Final  : ', final_list)
```

**Result**

```
Source :  [1, 3, 2, 10]
Final  :  [30, 1, 53, 4]
```